# How I do define a class method that accepts a derived class member function pointer as a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, observer-pattern

I'm using a Signal-Slot C++ implementation found here: https://github.com/pbhogan/Signals to implement event listeners within a user interface library I'm developing.

The user-facing API goes like so:

```
class DialEventListener : public EventListener {

    void handleEvent(Event event){
        …
        cout << "Event on" << event.source.name << end;
    }
}
int main(){
    Interactor dial1;
    dial1.addListener(ROTATE_EVENT, DialEventListener());
    … 
}
```

To define an event listener, a user would subclass `EventListener` to create a custom event handler. But in the implementation of `Interactor::addListener()` where I use the Signals.h code you have to provide a member function pointer as well as a class instance pointer to connect a Delegate to some Signal.

Below is an code snippet showing how I'm trying to use Signals to implement event listeners. I use a map from `EventType`s to `Signal` to account for an interactor that triggers multiple types of events.

```
typedef map< EventType, Signal1<Event> > EventTypeListenerMap;
class Interactor {

private:
   EventTypeListenerMap listener_map;

public:
   void TriggerEvent(Event e){
       Signal1<Event> signal = listener_map[e.type];
       signal(e);
   }

   void addListener(EventType e_type, EventListener listener){
      …
          //Find the signal for a particular kind of event.
      Signal1<TUIKitEvent> signal = listener_map[e_type];
          //Plug a delegate into that signal's slot
      signal.Connect( &listener, &EventListener::handleEvent); 
   }
   void addListener(EventType e_type, EventListener listener, void (EventListener::*handler)(Event)){
      …
      Signal1<TUIKitEvent> signal = listener_map[e_type];
      signal.Connect( &listener, handler); 
   }

}    

class EventListener  {
    virtual void handleEvent(Event event){
    }
}
```

The fact that I'm using a Signal-Slot implementation should be hidden from the user, so I just wrote this version of `Interactor::addListener(EventType, EventListener, void (EventListener::*))` as a sanity check to make sure I was passing the right member function pointer to be bound to that signal. But member function pointers are class specific, so how can one define a function with a signatures that accepts pointers to methods of classes derived from EventListener, which likely don't yet exist?

Comment: I don't think that the question is really clear... why do you want to pass a member function pointer to a derived method and not just a member function to the base type and have the dynamic dispatch resolve the final overrider for you? Maybe you should add a small piece of code pointing out what the user code looks like and the behavior you want from it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches for callbacks, either you provide an interface that has a virtual function that will be called, or else you perform *type-erasure* to make it fully generic. In the second version you either use a prepacked solution for the *type-erasure* or you will need to use some templates to implement it yourself.

The expected user code that you show in the first block follows the first approach, and is sufficient for the basic needs. But note that you will probably want to use pointers or references in a couple of the places where you are passing by value:

```
// user code
Interactor dial;
DialEventListener dial_listener;
dial.addListener( ROTATE_EVENT, dial_listener );

// implementation
void Interactor::addListener( EventType event, EventListener & listener ) {
   Signal1<TUIKitEvent> & sgn = listener_map[event];
   sgn.Connect( &listener, &EventListener::handleEvent );
};
```

Note a couple of changes: the `listener` argument is passed by reference rather than value. If you pass by value you will get *slicing* (only the `EventListener` subobject will be copied, and it will not be a `DialEventListener` object inside `addListener`. By passing a reference to the base type, you can use it as a base while the object maintains its identity.

That in turn requires that the object you pass in is not a temporary (you cannot use `DialEventListener()` as second argument to `addListener`, as the lifetime of the temporary will end at the end of the full expression and that means you will have a dangling reference (in your current implementation you have a dangling pointer inside the signal implementation, which will most probably cause UB once the signal is triggered).

Additionally, inside `addListener` you don't want to *copy* the signal stored in the map, but rather modify it, so again, you should use a reference rather than a value when accessing the signal in the map.

The documentation of your class should be quite explicit in that the lifetime of the object passed in must outlive the `Interactor` (or else allow for *deregistration* so that the client can remove the handler from the `Interactor` before the callback is destroyed (again, if you don't you will end in UB)

The other approach is performing *type-erasure*, I have never used that particular signals library so I am playing by ear here. The signal library that you are using (probably) implements type-erasure internally, but you need to be able to forward the exact type until the lib can perform the erasure, or else use a different type erasure library in the interface.

```
// Transferring the exact type to the signal lib:
class Interactor {
// ...
public:
   template <typename Listener>
   void addListener( EventType event, Listener & listener, void (Listener::*callback)(Event) ) {
      Signal1<TUIKitEvent> & sgn = listener_map[event];
      sgn.connect( &listener, callback );
   }
//...
```

Using a different type erasure library in the interface might or not be possible depending on the semantics of the `connect` method in your signals implementation. If it copies the first argument, then you can probably make do with `std::function`:

```
class Interactor {
//...
public:
   void addListener( EventType event, std::function< void (Event) > callback ) {
       Signal1<TUIKitEvent> & sgn = listener_map[event];
       sgn.connect( callback, &std::function<void(Event)>::operator() );
   }
//...
};
```

Assuming that the library will *copy* the first argument and maintain it's own copy internally (i.e. assuming that it behaves somehow like `boost::signal` library). On the user side, they will have to perform the type erasure:

```
struct AnotherListener {   // no need to explicitly derive from EventListner now!
   void method( Event e ) {}
};
int main() {
   Interactor dial;
   AnotherEventListener listener;
   dial.addListener( dial, std::bind( &AnotherListener::method, &listener ) );
}
```

The exact syntax of `bind` might not be that, I have never used it from the new standard in the boost library it would have been `boost::bind( &AnotherListener::method, &listener, _1 );`...

Comment: Both methods work. My original problem was that I wasn't passing the listener in by reference, which was why it was calling EventListener::handleEvent() and not DialEventListener::handleEvent().   I stumbled upon something similar to the 2nd approach where I created a function template like so: `template<class T, class U>addListener(EventType, T listener,  void (U::handleEvent)(Event))`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I find it slightly amusing that, having a library that performs type erasure (and thus frees the user from implementing an exact interface) you would just wrap that up with what is a less flexible approach...

Comment: It was probably some other error on my part that I eventually eliminated, but the library's erasure has two class parameters and since member function pointers are class specific that may have been my issue: See `template< class X, class Y >
 void Connect( Y * obj, void (X::*func)() )
 {
  delegateList.insert( MakeDelegate( obj, func ) );
 }`

Comment: As I said, I don't know that library, but I have used `boost::signal` library before (it has been changed into `boost::signal2` IIRC) and it was quite flexible in what it allowed (by combining the library with `boost::bind` (in C++11 you can use `std::bind`)... just saying...